# Does my laptop support M.2 SATA SSD?

Tags: laptop, ssd, pcie, sata

I have a dell inspiron 5575 laptop, ans the specification sheet of my laptop only mentions M.2 NvMe SSD slot in my laptop, does that mean M.2 SATA SSD wil not work in that slot?? I don't want to replace my HDD with SSD, I only wish to add an internal M.2 SATA SSD in my laptop.
[image: dell inspiron 5575 specification sheet]

Answer (score 1):

M.2 SATA SSD may not work in this slot.
SATA M.2 SSDs and 2.5-inch SATA SSDs - in fact, work with the same characteristics. NVMe M.2 drives work on the PCIe bus, and these are completely different indicators in throughput, they are significantly higher than the SATA bus.

[laptop support SATA M.2 SSD or NVMe M.2 SSD](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/does-this-laptop-support-sata-m-2-ssd-or-nvme-m-2-ssd.3057815/)

[5575 Inspiron and M.2 Nvme drives](https://www.dell.com/community/Inspiron/5575-Inspiron-and-M-2-Nvme-drives-anyone-with-experience/td-p/7251618)